# Change height of COMBOBOX

Tags: c, winapi

How can I change the height of a `COMBOBOX` control created with a resource-definition at runtime, so that I can insert new strings in the combobox? The string insertion code is working but only if I set a fixed height for the combobox in the resource-definition (e.g. 28 units). But this is not convenient, because the number of strings is dynamic.

I know that I can create the dialog at runtime, but then I can't use dialog units, and resources are much more efficient...

Here are simplified versions of my code.

**Resource file:**

```
IDD_SETTINGS DIALOG 0, 0, 100, 100
BEGIN
    COMBOBOX IDC_COMBO, 0, 0, 100, 14, CBS_DROPDOWNLIST
END
```

**Window procedure for main window and dialog:**

```
BOOL CALLBACK WndProcSettings(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            //...
            break;
        default:
            return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcMain(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
                case IDC_SETTINGS:
                    DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_SETTINGS), hWnd, WndProcSettings);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return(0L);
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you mean.
How this "change the height of a COMBOBOX control" and "insert new strings in the combobox" are related? COMBOBOX window has fixed height that depends only on system font size.

Comment: You can't see new inserted strings if the height is too small. The height parameter for the `COMBOBOX` resource includes the height of the dropdown area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I found a solution. Here is what I'm using now. I set the height for the combobox in the resource file to 14 DLU's (height of one item), so that the new height is calculated correctly. Using `GetClientRect` I get this height, and convert it to pixels with `MapDialogRect`.

```
HWND hCtl;
RECT rect;

hCtl = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_COMBO);
GetClientRect(hCtl, &rect);
MapDialogRect(hCtl, &rect);
SetWindowPos(hCtl, 0, 0, 0, rect.right, (n_choices + 1) * rect.bottom, SWP_NOMOVE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the height of the dropdown portion of the combobox.

You can still work with Dialog Units, take a look at [GetDialogBaseUnits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645475%28VS.85%29.aspx) which will return the number of pixels per dialog unit. If you are working with a non-system font the following KB article details the calculations - [How To Calculate Dialog Base Units with Non-System-Based Font](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125681).

You can programatically change the size of the combobox by using [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I tried with `SetWindowPos`, but then I only want to change the height. Not the x, y, and width. How can I do that?

Comment: SetWindowPos take a number of flags which control which values are meaningful. For example `SWP_NOMOVE` instructs SetWindowPos to ignore the `x, y` values, so using the right combination of flags you can adjust just the specific values you intend to adjust. And of course you can get the current window width and height and then pass those to SetWindowPos only adjusting the height. GetWindowRect for example could be used to get the current width etc.